# Button click in web browser

Tags: c#, html, browser

I have created web browser, now i want to by clicking button1 on my form click the button on the web.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("search").SetAttribute("value", IP.Text);
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

But i can't get a button id from this string

```
<input type="submit" value="→" class="button">
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your <input /> doesn't have an ID set so you can't call GetElementById. An empty string is not a valid id.

Comment: If you're getting an element by id, you should probably give it an id. <input type="submit" value="→" id="search" class="button">

Comment: i'm not creating the web page, i try to load already existed

Comment: Does the <form> element that you are submitting have an id?

Comment: http://whois-service.ru/lookup/ - as i can see - nope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Iterating over all of the `<input>` elements in the webpage. When you find one with the value you want, you could click that element.

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
{
    if (el.GetAttribute("value").Equals("→"))
    {
        el.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: but how can i make the same without webBrowser1? somehow it is possible to make this webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("search").SetAttribute("value", "0.0.0.0"); via url, right? something like http://web-site.com/index.php?value="0.0.0.0"

Comment: @fen1ksss You could use the `HttpWebRequest` class and submit a post request to http://whois-service.ru/lookup/ . Your request body would be `domain=255.255.255.255&real=true2.1simpleJ`, and replace 255.255.255.255 with whatever ip you want to look up. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx for more info

Comment: Thank you, it has really helped! and the last question, as i read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) web request send request to a particular uri, so i can somehow add 'domain=255.255.255.255&real=true2.1simpleJ' to my url? something like this  whois-service.ru/lookup/.php?domain=255.255.255.255&real=true2.1simpleJ or no?

Comment: You should make a POST request with that instead of appending it onto your URL. This site explains better on how to do a POST request: http://en.csharp-online.net/HTTP_Post

Answer (score 4):

The website doesn't prevent POSTing a form to it. So you could always just create your own webpage with the form that points to it.

HTML

```
<form id="search" action="http://whois-service.ru/lookup/" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="text" name="domain" id="domain" />
    <input type="submit" value="" class="button" />
    <input id="submit" type="hidden" name="real" value="true2.1simpleJ" />
</form>
```

c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = "[The HTML from above here]";
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("domain").SetAttribute("value", IP.Text);
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

If you are planning on scraping the WHOIS information. You must ensure it's not against the terms and conditions to do so. Most WHOIS services don't allow automated checks.

If they do and that's what you are trying to do then you should consider using HttpWebRequest instead, it's much more efficient. See an example here on how to use http://swhobby.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/c-example-of-http-post.html

Comment: there is standard windows nslookup-program, probably i'll try to work with it

Comment: is it a opposit way? click button in webcontrol get call button1_Click?