# Press button on webbrowser

Tags: c#, button, browser

I have a youtube page loaded (http://www.youtube.com/user/SeaNanners/videos) and I would like to press the 'Load More' button, I have tired several things such as;

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
        {
            if (el.GetAttribute("class").Equals("yt-uix-load-more load-more-button yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-default yt-uix-button-size-default"))
            {
                    el.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
```

As well as attempting other answers given on similar questions;
[C# How to Click Button auttomaticly via WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233151/c-sharp-how-to-click-button-auttomaticly-via-webbrowser)
[Button click in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182530/button-click-in-web-browser)

None seem to actually push the button.

Comment: do you even find the button or rather will the el.InvokeMember called?

Comment: Have a look at the source, its not really that clear on either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, quick and dirty maybe you can write it a little bit more graceful ;-)

**UPDATE:**

I´ve read your [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719399/load-all-the-videos-from-a-youtube-channel-for-streaming) that you asked before, and updated the code accordingly.
With this piece of code all Videos of a channel gets loaded (this may take a while with the webbrowserControl)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool found = true;
    while (found)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            found = ClickLoadMoreButton();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
}

private bool ClickLoadMoreButton()
{
    var buttons = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
    foreach (HtmlElement el in buttons)
    {
        var firstChild = el.FirstChild;
        if (firstChild != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstChild.InnerText))
            {
                if (firstChild.InnerText.ToLower().Replace(" ", string.Empty).Equals("loadmore"))
                {
                    el.InvokeMember("click");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There isnt even any button ID named that, for my youtube anyway.
http://i.imgur.com/TVTNLib.png

Comment: Read my post again, You are getting the wrong thing.
(I want the 'Load More' button to be clicked, the one that is on the channel page of a user, I.E. so I can load all their videos
http://i.imgur.com/HrE5tbD.png

Comment: I'll try it tonight by myself, maybe I´ll figure out what is going wrong

Comment: That would be very helpful, I need a solution to this. I have no idea why its so hard D:

Comment: I´ve read your question that you asked before, check my updated answer to load all videos of a channel

Comment: Sorry for the late responce!

Thank you SOOOOO much bro<3 means alot to me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808990/get-current-webbrowser-dom-as-html
You should totally have a look :3