# How can i click on a button in web page using webbrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

The last div variable with the elementid is working: "ctl00_RightMainContent_submitAddress_p_submitButtom"

The problem is with the items1 variable part.
I want to click the button you can see in the screenshot it's marked.
The class name is "addImg" and the onClick is openUploadDiv(0)
But not like in the div variable in the bottom this onClick openUploadDiv(0) i can't find it's id. And i tried to add as className "addImg" in the foreach but it didn't find it.

What i want it to do is to click automatic on the addImg button.

```
void webBrowser4_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri != webBrowser4.Url.AbsoluteUri)
            {
                return;
            }

            HtmlElementCollection items = webBrowser4.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
            foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "elements")
                {
                    webBrowser4.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_RightMainContent_txt_subject").InnerText = "DB החוקר מ סי.אס.איי";
                }
            }


            HtmlElementCollection items1 = webBrowser4.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
            foreach (HtmlElement item in items1)
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "elements")
                {
                    // openUploadDiv(0);
                    var div1 = webBrowser4.Document.GetElementById("file-input");
                    if (div1 != null)
                    {
                        var button = div1.All[0];
                        if (button != null)
                            button.InvokeMember("click");
                        else
                            MessageBox.Show("Button not found.");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            var div = webBrowser4.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_RightMainContent_submitAddress_p_submitButtom");
            if (div != null)
            {
                var button = div.All[0];
                if (button != null)
                    button.InvokeMember("click");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Button not found.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("div not found.");
            }
        }
```

And this is a screenshot when i did inspect element

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you click a button in a webbrowser control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271737/how-do-you-click-a-button-in-a-webbrowser-control) and [C# How to Click Button auttomaticly via WebBrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233151/c-sharp-how-to-click-button-auttomaticly-via-webbrowser) and [Button click in web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182530/button-click-in-web-browser). A google search will find you a multitude more.

Comment: C-Pound Guru this is working. Thanks.